# Issues saving and creating files on an external harddrive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, external-hard-drive

I recently formatted my system and installed Windows 7. When I connect my 500GB external USB harddrive, I seem to have some sort of permission problem which is preventing me from creating or saving files. When I right-click and choose "New", the menu lists only folders being available for creation.

What is causing this on my external drive and what can I do to fix it? I'm hoping for a solution other than changing ownership because that would take a couple of hours...

Answer (score 0):

Right click your external, properties, permissions.

Comment: including my user, admin, system , everyone have full control, whats next?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think taking ownership takes THAT long. It's a rather efficient process when I've done it, albeit scary (for me).

If you're not trying to change files in the previous user's folders, it should be even easier... to "take ownership of a folder in windows 7"